# java.awt.HeadlessException launching JavaFX app from Kotlin REPL

Tags: java, swing, javafx, kotlin, read-eval-print-loop

Hi I am trying to launch a simple JavaFx application from Kotlin's REPL to display a chart.

The code to launch the app is straightforward, but I get a

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:233)
at com.github.lwhite1.tablesaw.plotting.fx.FxPlot.getJfxPanel(FxPlot.java:13)
at com.github.lwhite1.tablesaw.api.plot.Pareto.initAndShowGUI(Pareto.java:65)
at com.github.lwhite1.tablesaw.api.plot.Pareto.lambda$show$1(Pareto.java:41)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Googling, I found reference to this command, which I ran:

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false")
```

true

but the problem continues, and I get the same error using Swing. How can I display GUI objects from the REPL?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have been informed by Intellij that this is not currently possible. An issue has been opened: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18181.

Update: The issue has been fixed for version 1.1.4. (That took Intellij about 3 days. They ain't foolin' around).